# How do I set and get color using textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox and a `type=color`. When I change color using the color control it should set a value in the textbox and when I change value in color textbox it should change in color control.

How can I make this reflect immediately when full color code is typed?

I have tried with this:

```js
function changeColor() {
  var color = document.getElementById("coltext").value.trim(),
    rxValidHex = /^#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i;

  if (rxValidHex.test(color)) {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = color;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid CSS Hex Color");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="coltext" />
<input type=color id="color" />
```

Comment: How do you call `changeColor` function  ?

Comment: How do I make when user keeps typing until the correct code

Comment: You should take a look to the documentation on MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color  The `Tracking color changes` section will help you, I tink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen for input change on both the elements.

As the `color` input only accept 7 character hex strings you will need to convert 4 digit shorthand hex strings for them to work properly.

```js
var coltext = document.getElementById('coltext');
var colpick = document.getElementById('color');

// Listen to changes in the colortext input
coltext.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  // If the input is a valid 7 character hex string
  // assign this value to the color picker
  if( this.value.match(/^#([0-9a-f]{6})$/)) {
   colpick.value = this.value;
  }
  // If the input is a valid 4 character hex string
  // convert it to a 7 character hex string and 
  // assign this value to the color picker
  else if( this.value.match(/^#([0-9a-f]{3})$/ )) {
    var r = this.value[1],
        g = this.value[2],
        b = this.value[3];
    colpick.value = `#${r}${r}${g}${g}${b}${b}`;
  }
})

// If a new color is picked, display its value
// in the text input field
colpick.addEventListener("input", function(e){
  coltext.value = this.value;
})
```

```html
<input type=text id="coltext" />
<input type=color id="color" />
```

---

**Edit:** It's probably faster to concatenate the strings and print the result using only one template literal expression - instead of six separate expressions as shown in my original answer. So while both will work, the following line is probably more elegant and performing slightly better than the solution above:

```
colpick.value = `#${r+r+g+g+b+b}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", startup, false);

function startup() {
  colorWell = document.querySelector("#color");
  document.querySelector("#coltext").value = colorWell.value;
  colorWell.addEventListener("input", updateInput, false);
  colorWell.addEventListener("change", updateInput, false);
  colorInput = document.querySelector("#coltext");
  colorInput.addEventListener("input", updateColorInput, false);
  colorInput.addEventListener("change", updateColorInput, false);
}

function updateInput(event) {
 document.querySelector("#coltext").value = event.target.value;
}

function updateColorInput(event){
 document.querySelector("#color").value = event.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input type=text id="coltext" />
<input type=color id="color" />
```

You can add eventlistener `input` and `change` from the event get and set values.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. Instead of trying to set `color` attribute of the element, what you're looking for is the `value` attribute.

Also, to get the Javascript to work as you intended it to, you should add calls to them for the proper events - `onBlur` for the textbox and `onChange` for the color control.

Check the changes I made on your code below.

```js
function changeColor() {
  var color = document.getElementById("coltext").value.trim(),
    rxValidHex = /^#(?:[0-9a-f]{3}){1,2}$/i;

  if (rxValidHex.test(color)) {
    document.getElementById("color").value = color;
  } else {
    alert("Invalid CSS Hex Color");
    document.getElementById("coltext").value = "";
  }
}

function selectNewColor(){
document.getElementById("coltext").value = document.getElementById("color").value;
} // end of function selectNewColor
```

```html
<input type=text id="coltext" onBlur="changeColor()"/>
<input type=color id="color" onChange="selectNewColor()" />
```